# Getting Nil Date when converting from NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

Getting nil date in converting NSString to NSDate when using the app in Columbia but in India its working fine. Not getting the exact solution. Can somebody help?

I am using this code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; 
NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]; 
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",newDateString,@"08:00:00"]; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterToSaveDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterToSaveDate setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *dateToSave = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
dateToSave = [dateFormatterToSaveDate dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: what is the string date format?

Comment: using this @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: in the US the format will be "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I will launch the app globally than it is not practically possible to check time zone for each region. So that the Date will not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
**NSString to NSDate**

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010 05:30:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: i need to insert time also. Like this @"29-05-2015 08:00:00" and using this formatter @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Comment: @MayankBarnwal then just use @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" instead of @"dd-MM-yyyy".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a locale issue and it's sort of the same of NSDateFormatter Strings in iOS 7, just the other way around.

Try setting the locale to en_US or to currentLocale

```
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
or

NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the date string you are converting coming from? user input? db? some other webservice?

either the string is a fixed format (ie its from a db/web service) in which case you need to convert it with a fixed format, or the string is user input and so will be in the locale the user is in and so you need to convert it with the users locale.

Comment: please put the code in your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of the difference between device's time format & your date's time format. Try setting the correct timezone & locale.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:locale];
```

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> If you're working with fixed-format dates, you should first set the
>   locale of the date formatter to something appropriate for your fixed
>   format. In most cases the best locale to choose is en_US_POSIX, a
>   locale that's specifically designed to yield US English results
>   regardless of both user and system preferences. en_US_POSIX is also
>   invariant in time (if the US, at some point in the future, changes the
>   way it formats dates, en_US will change to reflect the new behavior,
>   but en_US_POSIX will not), and between platforms (en_US_POSIX works
>   the same on iPhone OS as it does on OS X, and as it does on other
>   platforms).
>
> Once you’ve set en_US_POSIX as the locale of the date formatter, you
>   can then set the date format string and the date formatter will behave
>   consistently for all users.